# Adding two arrays using for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to add two array using only for loop but it is not working

The Code:

```
# Adding two arrays using For loop
from numpy import *
arr1 = array([2, 6, 8, 9, 1])
arr2 = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
arrSum = array([])
for i in range(5):
    arrSum[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i]
print(arrSum)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\Python\First Project\main.py", line 241, in <module>
    arrSum[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Comment: do you have to use numpy for this?

Comment: Why do you want to use "only for loop"? It's very slow and inefficient and defeats the purpose of using numpy.

Comment: Its just a practice code so only for loop and yes I can only use array or numpy

Comment: Note that you cannot, even in plain Python, set the value in a list or array at an index which does not exist. You either need to preallocate the `arrSum` or use `.append`. Again though, why loop? This can be achieved with a single operator.

Comment: Why are you practicing a technique you should never use in numpy? If you want to practice doing this with normal Python, then a `for` loop would be appropriate -- and good practice. But doing it in numpy will not give you applicable skills for the future because you should never do this in numpy with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this super simply with numpy:

```py
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([2, 6, 8, 9, 1])
arr2 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

arrSum = arr1 + arr2

print(arrSum)
```

```
Output:

[ 3  8 11 13  6]
```

To do it using a `for` loop defeats the purpose of using numpy (i.e. efficient, optimised array operations), but an example using regular Python lists would be:

```py
arr1 = [2, 6, 8, 9, 1]
arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

arr_sum = [a + b for a, b in zip(arr1, arr2)]

print(arr_sum)
```

```
[3, 8, 11, 13, 6]
```

Comment: added an example with for loop